# echo elements of an array outputs nothing

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

This is basically a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887564/bash-one-liner-works-but-script-does-not?noredirect=1#comment67062048_39887564). The following script prompts the user for a search string and then returns a numbered list of `history` commands containing that string.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Search history for? ' string

i=0
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

HISTFILE="$HOME/.bash_history"
history -r
arr=( "$(history | grep -i "$string" | cut -c8-)" )

for item in ${arr[@]}
do
    echo "$(( i++ )) $item"
done
```

I wanted to extend this by then asking the user to select one of the commands listed

```
read -p 'select a command or type /q to quit ' n
if [[ $n = '/q' ]]; then
    exit
else
    for cmd in ${arr[$n]}
    do
        echo "$cmd"
    done
fi
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

However this returns nothing every time. I've used this same sort of selection method before with success. Why doesn't this work in this particular scenario?

Comment: Array arr contains only one element.

Comment: @user556068: Aside from why Cyrus said (i.e. your use of double quotes makes the array contain only one element), shouldn't you turn on the history mechanism, i.e. `set -o history`?

Comment: @user1934428 That option is needed only if there is the need to store the commands executed in the history file, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array `arr` has only one element `0` because you are assigning the quoted result of the command. Try using the index 0. And also try this (no quotes):

```
arr=( $(history | grep -i "$string" | cut -c8-) )
```

Now that the reason is clear, the solution should be something like:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a arr <<<"$(history | grep -i "$string" | cut -c8-)"
```

Or (bash > 4.0):

```
readarray -t arr <<<"$(history | grep -i "$string" | cut -c8-)"
```

Why the change? To split the result on newlines and to avoid the expansion of '*' and others from "Pathname expansion".

---

Also, you do not need a loop to print one item, use this instead:

```
read -p 'select a command or type /q to quit ' n
[[ $n = '/q' ]] && exit
echo "command for $n -- ${arr[n]}"
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want use the built-in select:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Search history for? ' string

i=0
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

HISTFILE="$HOME/.bash_history"
history -r
arr=$(history | grep -i "$string" | cut -c8-)

select choice in $arr; do echo "your choice is $choice"; break; done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Output:

```
...
33) kill -l                  
#? 33
your choice is kill -l
```